# Specify the subspecs of dependency in a podspec

Tags: cocoapods

looking for this functionality in a podspec

```rb
  s.dependency "MetaWear", '~> 4.1.3', :subspecs => ['UI', 'AsyncUtils']
```

I basically need to specify the subspecs of dependency, seems like this should just work but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is specified anywhere but this works

```rb
  s.dependency "MetaWear", '~> 4.1.3'
  s.dependency "MetaWear/AsyncUtils"
```